# How to access state from closure in React

Tags: reactjs, closures, javascript-objects

My assumption is that I try to access state from a closure.
This does somehow not work:

**Present Code:**

```js
export class CityChoice extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={}
}

componentDidMount(){
  request
    .get('http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX:3000/get_courses')
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .then((res) => {
        for (let key in res.body){
          console.log(res.body[key].city)
        }
      this.setState({courses: res.body})
        console.log("this.state.courses -> " + this.state.courses)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    });
}

render(){
  var that = this
  return (<div>
            <h2>Wähle Deine Stadt</h2>
            {
            that.state.courses.body.city.map((city, index) => (
              <p><Link to={{pathname: "/kurse", stadt: {city}}}><Button>{city}</Button></Link></p>
            ))}
            }
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Expected Result**

Output of x Buttons named and linked to the respective cities.

**Actual Result**

TypeError: that.state.courses is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component tries to render `courses` before your async fetch finishes. So, use a conditional rendering if you can't initialize your courses to an appropriate null state as @Tarik Sahni suggested.

```
{
    !this.state.courses
    ? ""
    : this.state.courses.body.city.map((city, index) => (
        <p><Link to={{pathname: "/kurse", stadt: {city}}}><Button>{city}</Button></Link></p>
    ))}
}
```

or maybe more concise

```
{
    this.state.courses && this.state.courses.body.city.map((city, index) => (
        <p><Link to={{pathname: "/kurse", stadt: {city}}}><Button>{city}</Button></Link></p>
    ))}
}
```

You don't need to assign `this` to `that` in your render function

Answer (score 2):

courses are being fetched from server, so the response will come after the request is processed. But in the initial render function there is no state property called `courses`. So you can set them as empty in constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state={courses : {`what so ever is the data type`}}
}
```

And while rendering  check whether `this.state.courses` is not empty.

Comment: You mean that probably the data is not yet there while the rendering takes place?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on the shape of your data. You loop through `res.body`, accessing its values and printing out a value with key city from each of them in this code:

```
    for (let key in res.body){
      console.log(res.body[key].city)
    }
```

You then assign `res.body` to a `courses` key in `this.state`
This implies a state shape somewhat like:

```
this.state = {
  courses: [
         { city: "New York"},
         { city: "San Francisco"},
         { city: "Jerusalem"},
         { city: "Ho Chi Minh"}
        ]
}
```

(`courses` could be an object too, but array made more sense to me)
However, when you access the state, you write the following expression:
`that.state.courses.body.city.map`. This implies that the state looks closer to:

```
this.state = {
  courses: {
    body: {
      city: [
          "New York",
          "San Francisco",
          "Jerusalem",
          "Ho Chi Minh"
      ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Now because this is JavaScript, it could be that you have both in state shapes in the same object. But frankly that seems both unlikely, and if so, ill-advised. My suggestion is to simplify the state shape so that undefined errors can be isolated to specific parts of your state that are missing. And if it must be a complicated state, write out the format.